# Add image to registration email

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails

I have some issues getting the registration email that I want. I have changed the language override to have the text I want. But now I want to add some images, logo and signature to the email.

But how do I do that? When I add the image tag to the language override it just displays the image tag.

If possible I'd like to not use plugins or components. Email beautifier is a thing, but I'd like to not use that and use smaller plugins or code hacks.

Comment: Is the image you are trying to display related the language, e.g. a country flag for a specific language, or is the image unrelated to the override? It would be a lot easier to understand what you are trying to achieve if you posted up some examples of the code/override  that you already have and if possible a sample of the final result you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It's not related to the language. But as far as I understand you cnanot actually override the email itself, if you want to override the contents of the email you need to change the language override, which I did, but I cannot override the email itself. It would be a LOT EASIER if you can override it like the rest but that is as far as i know not possible.

Comment: A language override just replaces the constant with the text of the override so I can't picture how you are trying to include an image etc. hence why I asked for an example of what you have attempted. 
In Joomla 4 the ability to provide alternative emails templates that replace the core emails sent for things like new registrations is available.
For Joomla 3 you are relying on 3rd party extension to do anything more than string replacement.

Comment: Ok so I guess my only option is to use a 3rd party extension? Isn't it possible to make a very simple plugin that catches/overrides the method for setting up the content of the email or something?

Comment: The Acymail component, newsletters, has/had, had the ability to change the core emails and a quick search in the JED shows a number of extensions to change the emals also, https://extensions.joomla.org/instant-search/?jed_live%5Bquery%5D=email&jed_live%5BrefinementList%5D%5Btags_array%5D%5B0%5D=Email